# Overlapping rows in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my HTML document there are two tables having 4 and 1 rows respectively. I want to put the row of the second table on the top of last row of the first table. I tried using z-index but the overlapping is not proper

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table1">
            <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
                <th>DESIGNATION</th>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="limegreen">
                <td>John</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Front-End Developer</td>
            <tr>
            <tr bgcolor="lime">
                <td>Angelov</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Back-End Developer</td>
            <tr>
            <tr bgcolor="limegreen">
                <td>Rishi</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Full-Stack Developer</td>
            <tr>
            <tr bgcolor="lime">
                <td>Amy</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Web Designer</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table id="table2">
            <tr bgcolor="lime">
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Database Administrator</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refer to this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
At least put up your css, so everyone can see what you have done

Answer (score 0):

As a quick example you could position both of them absolutely so the second table sits on top of the first one ? You may need to add more css styles to make the table design consistent

```css
#table1 {
position: absolute;
width: 253px;
}

#table2 {
position: absolute;
width: 253px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table1">
            <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
                <th>DESIGNATION</th>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="limegreen">
                <td>John</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Front-End Developer</td>
            <tr>
            <tr bgcolor="lime">
                <td>Angelov</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Back-End Developer</td>
            <tr>
            <tr bgcolor="limegreen">
                <td>Rishi</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Full-Stack Developer</td>
            <tr>
            <tr bgcolor="lime">
                <td>Amy</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Web Designer</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
        <table id="table2">
            <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
                <th>DESIGNATION</th>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="limegreen">
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Database Administrator</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```